# How to access specific array index and display it?

Tags: php, arrays

So in this project i have 3 PHP files, namely `index.php`, `processor.php`, and `viewsubmission.php`

My `index.php` and `processor.php` both works perfectly fine as I intended, my problem here now is in the `viewsubmission.php`.

when I run this file it only shows this:

[image]

is there a possible way where I could display a text before the data that comes from the text file? The expected output should be like this.

[image]

second problem: How can I display the new data without having to removed the first set of data that being displayed.

**index.php** //contains my form

```
<form action = "Processor.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Student ID:<input type="text" name="studentId"><br>
    Student Name: <input type="text" name="studentName"><br>
    Activity Number: <input type="text" name="activityNumber"><br>
    Comment: <input type="text" name="comment"><br>
    File Upload (doc,docx, & pdf files only):<br><input type="file" name="fileupload"> <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit File</button>
</form>
```

**Processor.php** //code all the inputs in the form gets process then write in the text file

```
//creating the name of the file
$newFileName = uniqid('',true) . "." . $FileExt;
//identify file destination
$fileDst = "uploads/" . $newFileName;
move_uploaded_file($TempFile, $fileDst);

//Write data in textfile
$file = fopen("uploads/data.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $_POST['studentId'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $_POST['studentName'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $_POST['activityNumber'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $_POST['comment'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $fileDst . "\n");
fclose($file);

echo "<br><br>>New file Location: " . $fileDst . "<br>";
echo "Record Saved...";
```

**viewsubmission.php** //access the file and read its contents and display it

```
<?php
    $filePath = "uploads/data.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filePath);

    $values = explode("\n", $content);

    echo "<hr>";

    $numberofData = 0;
    foreach($values as $val){  
        echo $val . "<br>";
        $numberofData++;
    }
    $numberofData--;
    echo "<hr>";
```

Comment: Consider saving it as [JSON](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to retain keys and values. Then decode when you load the text from your file; iterate `foreach($values as $key => $val){` and `echo "$key: $val";`.

Comment: could you share `Processor.php ` code too please, to check the whole logic of it together, 
also the problem is that it showing only one record or the updating look of returned data from the file ?

Comment: @OmarTammam I've edited and added the code for Processor.php . You are right, I'm also having trouble of showing all the records especially when I added new data in the textfile (It only shows one set of data).

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one question - [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to separate the rows from each other we need first to add any text as an identifier that this is the end of the row at the `Processor.php`
then at `viewsubmission.php` you will explode by this identifier to get the rows, then explode each row to get the values inside it

In my example, I will use this word `@@End@@` to detect the row end ~ *feel free to use your own identifier*

so at the `Processor.php`
i will add this line
`fwrite($file, "@@End@@");`

so the writing in the file will looks like this

```
//Write data in textfile
            $file = fopen("uploads/data.txt", "a");
            fwrite($file, $_POST['studentId'] . "\n");
            fwrite($file, $_POST['studentName'] . "\n");
            fwrite($file, $_POST['activityNumber'] . "\n");
            fwrite($file, $_POST['comment'] . "\n");
            fwrite($file, $fileDst . "\n");
            fwrite($file, "@@End@@");
            fclose($file);
```

and at the `viewsubmission.php`

```
<?php

    $filePath = "uploads/data.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filePath);

    //------- seprate rows
    $rows = explode("@@End@@", $content);
    
    //ignoring last element as it will always be empty after exploading @@End@@
    for($i =0; $i< count($rows)-1 ; $i++){
        
        $row = $rows[$i];
        
        $values = explode("\n", $row);      
        echo "<hr>";

        $numberofData = 0;
        foreach($values as $val){  
            echo $val . "<br>";
            $numberofData++;
        }
        $numberofData--;
        echo "<hr>";
    }
```

**N.B** we need to validate the inputs data & make sure that the identifier word is not allowed to be inserted by the user to avoid the break of logic, either by returning a validation error by `trim` it from the input value

**Alternatively,** you can save it in JSON as **@Markus AO** mentioned  will be a better solution using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
for saving & handling of data in JSON format instead of raw data

so the writing at `Processor.php` should be something like that

```
//Write data in textfile
            $row = [];
            $row["studentId"]       = $_POST['studentId'];
            $row["studentName"]     = $_POST['studentName'];
            $row["activityNumber"]  = $_POST['activityNumber'];
            $row["comment"]         = $_POST['comment'];
            
            $fileData = file_get_contents('uploads/data.json');
            $fileArray = json_decode($fileData);
            
            //if the file is empty or its the first record 
            if(!is_array($fileArray))
                $fileArray = [];
            
            array_push($fileArray, $row);
            
            $jsonData = json_encode($fileArray);
            file_put_contents('uploads/data.json', $jsonData);
```

and decoding at `viewsubmission.php` like that

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('uploads/data.json');
$rows = json_decode($file_data,true);

foreach($rows as $row){
    
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $row["studentId"] ."<br>";
    echo $row["studentName"] ."<br>";
    echo $row["activityNumber"] ."<br>";
    echo $row["comment"] ."<br>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

hope this helps!